# how to diff a record from database and DateTime

Tags: php, datetime

i try to make a diff between record from database and DateTime

[image]
this is my code

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "abb");
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM submission_abb");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$submission = $row['submission'];
$selesai = new DateTime();
$hitung = $submission->diff($selesai);
$result = $hitung->format('Y-m-d');
if($hitung->d <=3){
echo $result . "Ontime";
}else{
echo $result . "Over time";
}
?>
```

Comment: that was a typo, i have edited the code

Comment: Please update your question and remove the image and add the actual text of the error message

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you are calling `diff()` on a string value as `$submission` holds a date value which is a string. You can only call `diff()` on a `DateTime()` object.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "abb");
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM submission_abb");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$submission = new DateTime($row['submission']);
$selesai = new DateTime();
$hitung = $submission->diff($selesai);
$result = $hitung->format('Y-m-d');
if($hitung->d <=3){
echo $result . "Ontime";
}else{
echo $result . "Over time";
}
?>
```

Comment: any suggestions for make a diff from database record and DateTime() object? i just want to make a diff from submission_date and current_date, and make condition if the result <=3 then the lead time is ontime. could you help me?

Comment: thanks alot, it works. sorry for my english, im still learning